# How to monitor Unexpectedly exited Threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In multi thread programming, what if one of worker thread is unexpectedly exited and main thread needs to know whether that thread is alive or not.

Is there any way to check this?

I was wondering if there is a typical signal that is made when worker thread is exited.

(Linux)

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you query a pthread to see if it is still running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156353/how-do-you-query-a-pthread-to-see-if-it-is-still-running)

Comment: Well.. using flag seems useless since I've been talking about "unexpected exit"... if it exits nicely, I could have used those methods Thanks. Read that Questions before I wrote this :D

Comment: Do you have a big `try ... catch ` surrounding each thread body ? You could catch any thrown execption and use `cout << ex.what() << endl;`

Comment: hmm no.. haven't tried try catch.. will have to think about that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If threads are unexpectedly dying in your program, it is toast. If you want fault isolation, with recovery, use multiple processes (with shared memory) instead of, or inaddition to threads. On POSIX (and Win32 also) you can detect if the owner of a process-shared mutex died while holding that mutex and implement some "fsck-like" check and repair of the shared data to try to restore its invariants. (Obviously it helps you if the data structure is designed with recoverable transactions in mind.)

On Win32 you can use Windows structured exception handling (SEH) to catch any kind of exception in a thread. (For instance access violation, division by zero, ...). Using the tool help API you can gain a list of the attached modules, and there are interfaces for reading the machine registers, faulting address, etc.

In POSIX you can do that with signal handling. Events like access violations and such deliver signals to the thread to which they pertain.

It doesn't seem realistic to code up these pieces into a recovery strategy that tries to keep a buggy program running.

Comment: hmm still not getting the big picture though lol
I've figured out that by sending pthread_kill ( threadId , 0 ) you can just check the liveliness of thread (won't really kill it). Now I am wondering about how to free the resources of the unexpected dead threads.. I think i can do this with pthread_create_key... Still looking for ways