# Does pthread resets pthread_t value after finishing execution?

Tags: pthreads

first argument of pthread_create is pthread_t (which is typedef'ed to long), which I understand is thread ID.

Does it set this value to zero when thread finishes execution?
I would like to use it to check if the thread is running

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2156580/1256624

Answer (score 0):

No, the `pthread_t` isn't changed by the pthread library once it's initialized.  Pass the `pthread_t` object to `pthread_join()` to wait until the thread is finished.  If you want to determine without blocking, you can have the thread cooperate by setting an indicator for it's state in some shared object.