# Checking if a thread is unused C

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to check whether a thread in an array is unused and then return the space of the array unused

```
int Check(){
    int a;
    for (a=0;a<12;a++){
        if(tid[a]==0){
            return a;
        }
    }
    return -1;
```

tid is a global variable

```
pthread_t tid[12];
```

I am always getting the -1 return, I don't know how to check whether the thread is used or not.

I don't know what an unused pthread_t is equal to.

This is how I'm initializing the array:

```
user[i] = (struct users){i,0,count}; 
pthread_create(&tid[count], NULL, (void*)Actions, &user[i]);
```

Comment: How are you initializing your array elements?

Comment: why would you expect a pthread_t to ever equal zero?

Comment: i dont know what a unused pthread_t is equal to

Comment: user[i] = (struct users){i,0,count};
pthread_create(&tid[count], NULL, (void*)Actions, &user[i]);

Comment: Please, edit your question, instead of posting it at the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not track whether a `pthread_t` is being used or not simply by comparing it with a constant like you did. The contents of the `pthread_t` data type are purposedly not exposed to the programmer.

Consider declaring your array as an array of the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
    bool avaiable;
    pthread_t thread;
} threadrec_t;
```

Use the `threadrec_t.avaiable` field to identify whether the thread is in use or not. You must remember to set its value to `true` when giving usage to it, and `false` when the job is done.

Take a look at this some what related question:

[How do you query a pthread to see if it is still running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156353/how-do-you-query-a-pthread-to-see-if-it-is-still-running)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

In the main thread, call `pthread_self` and capture the return value somewhere; perhaps a global variable.

While the main thread is alive, the ID of any other thread cannot be equal to the ID of the main thread; so you can use this main thread ID as a special value to indicate "no thread here".

```
/* ... */

no_thread = pthread_self(); /* in main */

/* ... */

if (pthread_create(&tid[i], ...)) {
  /* failed */
  tid[i] = no_thread;
}

/* ... */
if (pthread_equal(tid[i], no_thread)) {
  /* no thread at index i */
}
```

The alternative is to have a parallel array `tid_valid[]` of booleans which indicate the validity of the corresponding `tid` values are present. Or a structure like:

```
struct thread_info {
  pthread_t id;
  int valid;
};
```

and make the `tid` array of these structures.