# Using Pthread_kill() to check whether a thread is terminated

Tags: c, pthreads

ret_kill=pthread_kill(thread_id,0);

if( ret_kill == 0)
{
`doesthis means the thread is still alive ?`
}

else
{

`does this mean thread is terminated and is joinable`

}

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156353/how-do-you-query-a-pthread-to-see-if-it-is-still-ru

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you query a pthread to see if it is still running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156353/how-do-you-query-a-pthread-to-see-if-it-is-still-running)