# is there a isAlive method in C to check the status of a thread?

Tags: c, pthreads, isalive

I need a method, like "isAlive" in java, to use in my C project to know the state of a pthread.
While I was searching online I didn't manage to find anything. Do you guys have any suggestion?

Comment: In case it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156353/how-do-you-query-a-pthread-to-see-if-it-is-still-running

Comment: Just because you mention Java, that doesn't mean the question is Java-related. Don't tag unrelated languages/technologies.

Comment: 'Do you guys have any suggestion?' sure - redesign so that such calls/methods are not required.