How can I clean up c++ terminated threads?
I have a program that does some background processing, in a separate thread. At the moment, I create it with:
terminate_thread = false;
threadhandle = std::make_shared<std::thread>([this]{MyProg::backgroundThread();});

before I terminate my program, I tell the thread to finish what they are doing, and join with it:
terminate_thread = true;
threadhandle->join();

My background thread isn't quick enough (it's doing network stuff), I'd like to change it to have a variable number of threads, so I am changing it to use an std::vector.
During the runtime of my program (which might be weeks), it might collect a lot of background threads (if the load varies). When the background threads detect there's not much work for them to do (or if they are told to terminate), they will exit the function.
If I was doing this with fork(), the forked processes remain in the process table as "zombies" until  and consume a finite (though large) resource. The parent process is notified of these with a signal, and such zombies should be cleaned up with e.g. wait(). Alternatively, you can waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG); . Either of these also lets the parent process update it's list of processes that are still running.
How can I tell which threads are finished? Do I need to join them, or can I just remove them from my list?
I am open to some method other than a std::vector of threads, so long as I can increase and decrease the number of threads dynamically. All the threads use the same function. No information needs to be transferred between background threads and the main program (or vice versa), or between threads (since I'm processing files, the files are locked).
I'm pretty new to C++ and threads.
I am writing/compiling/running this on Linux.
I tried threadhandle.use_count() and threadhandle.unique() threadhandle.joinable(), which always return 1, true, and true, even after the thread has terminated.
If I call threadhandle.join(), my main thread is blocked.
If I call detach(), I can't join() when I'm ready to terminate. The threads could potentially take a while (up to 30 seconds) to end, I definitely want them to have the chance to finish.
If I just collect them all up, I might have a very long list by the end (I am more used to fork(), which leaves Zombie processes if you don't clean them up).
I've searched Google, and stackoverflow. There are useful examples in Java and C#, but not C++
I could not find any way in the docs for std::thread - std::thread does not appear to have a "state" (or a way of getting the state).
I understand I could pass one variable to each thread, to let them say when they are done; this seems like a lot of overhead, for something that I would expect to be built in. It also wouldn't handle if a thread exits unexpectedly, e.g. an exception.

Maybe get a thread pool library?

"A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore joinable." When you want to exit the main thread you join the remaining threads; if they have finished already, join() returns immediately.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I don't know if threads that have finished executing code take up any resource, my list of threads will. I would like to (join if necessary and) discard the threads from the list long before I want the main thread to exit.

Idle threads (those waiting for IO or things like std::condition_variable)) indeed have some stack space allocated to them, but they also end up in an idle thread state (on the OS level!) which means they will no longer be scheduled by the OS (don't take up CPU time). detach you should indeed never use.  To "cleanup" a thread you just need to let it exit the backgroundThread function, but we cannot tell you how to do that because you don't show any code of that loop

@PepijnKramer backgroundThread backgroundThread has while (!terminate_thread) and (queue.length() != 0), so will self-terminate when appropriate. I am asking from the other side, the main thread. I guess the reason I am asking is that I'm used to fork(), which if not cleaned up with wait(), will accumulate zombie processes, and eventually run out of process ids. Also, the list of threads held by the main thread will grow without limit, so I'd like to keep that limited.

Pretty similar to the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156353/how-do-you-query-a-pthread-to-see-if-it-is-still-running

@JayBee -   If the threads clean themselves up appropriately, then your main thread should not need to do much more than notify the thread(s) to terminate and join/wait for them complete.    It is not rare for a forked process to be terminated in a manner outside control (or visibility) of the parent process.    The possibilities are much rarer for a thread in your program to be terminated outside control/visibility of your main thread.

Threads are not processes. If your thread self-terminates that is the right thing to do, the std::thread object will remain but the thread (running on the CPU) will have stopped and no longer exists. The call to std::thread::join will then immediately return (it has no thread to wait on). std::thread::join will only wait if the thread is still active.

Note that an unhandled exception in a thread will generally crash your program so failing to set the watch variable in that case isn't too much of a concern
